# How can server always sent massages on response of client one message in python?

Tags: python, sockets, client-server, serversocket

I am working o project where i need to connect to python server.
I have made socket server on python and when i sent request from client it sent me one reply.
I want to connect to the same client and send many messages from server.
I try this code but i need request from client all the time.

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import *
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 6666
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((host,port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(5)

print ('waiting for clinet')
def threaded_client(conn):
    k=1
    conn.send(str.encode('Welcome You are connected'))
    while True:
        k=k+1
        conn.send(str.encode('Loop',k))


while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print ('connected to : ' + addr[0] + str(addr[1]))    
    start_new_thread(threaded_client,(conn,))
```

Comment: What behavior are you expecting? What are you seeing? From the code you've shown, you are never even receiving a request from the client. However, I'm guessing your thread is actually seeing a `TypeError` exception in the `threaded_client` loop. `str.encode` does not take an integer argument.

Comment: conn, addr = s.accept() This line receiving request from client.

Comment: No. Or at least your terminology is confusing. `accept` does not receive an actual request. `accept` accepts the connection; it returns the newly connected socket object (`conn`) and the address from which the connection was initiated (`addr`). You need to call `conn.recv` in order to actually read any request sent by the client. (Still if your server doesn't actually care about request data from the client, it doesn't *need* to do a `recv` at all, in which case your current code structure should work fine -- *except* for the `str.encode` issue.)